# How to organize my data to create Q&A system with Faiss

Tags: faiss, vector-database

I am completely  new to faiss and Question answering  System,  I have several  csv file containing data from different topics like job information  , Coursera courses and ... around 10 csv file .My assignment  is to build a question answering System with Faiss . I would like to know  how to organize my data to create the system  ? Should I concatenate all of them and store them in a vector Database  ? If yes any recommendations ?

Comment: This is a great question. You should provide some code.

Comment: Hi here is  where I am currently trying to do some tests, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19YizApN6o0sNMPCmR0qvOfY7qu54AmYb?usp=sharing